# Firefox very laggy with a simple animation

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, animation, html

I'm prototyping a very simple UI where the user may scroll an infinite flow of thumbnails horizontally. I'm amazed by how can 16 moving divs be so slow in Firefox but so goddamn smooth and fast in Chrome, IE and opera?

This is the piece of code that's ran every 8 milliseconds with a setInterval:

```
function update() {
    for (t in thumbs) {
        thumbs[t].element.style.left = Math.round((thumbs[t].offset * width * 1) + (width / 2) + (thumbs[t].x * thumbWidth * 1.6) - thumbWidth / 2) + 'px';
        thumbs[t].element.style.top = Math.round(height*0.48 + (thumbs[t].y * thumbHeight * 0.7) - thumbHeight / 2)+'px';
        thumbs[t].element.style.width = thumbWidth+'px';
        thumbs[t].element.style.height = thumbHeight+'px';
        thumbs[t].offset = thumbs[t].offset + (thumbs[t].targetOffset - thumbs[t].offset) / 30;
    }
}
```

Here's a full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VbErB/

I realize it's not as optimized as it could be but it's not ridiculously heavy either. Chrome is updating at about 120 frames per second. I'm not sure about Firefox but it's definitely a **lot** less, with an uncomfortable amount of stuttering thrown in. This must be some commonly known quirk of Firefox that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: Seems to me you'd get a massive performance boost by moving their single parent container div instead of each one individually.

Comment: A good idea no doubt. I quickly tested with the number of thumbnails set to 1 (or 2 at once while animating) and there's no visible difference in performance at all. I can't possibly get it down from that.

Comment: So some of the values I can understand, but why do you need to reassign the top, width and height of every thumbnail every time?

Comment: The number of divs isn't the problem then, I meant to say. Maybe Firefox has some global 40fps limit or something? There's no way 2 moving divs is too much for any modern browser.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code so only style.left is set every frame. No difference.

Comment: Both running at the same speed here. Linux x64.  
Chrome: (18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux) Built on Ubuntu 12.04, running on LinuxMint 13)   
Firefox: (12.0 Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint mint - 1.0)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the thumbs in a container and animating that element instead?

Comment: I know that jQuery is very much optimized to perform animation as smoothly as possible and when animating just the "left" property of a single element it still performs as "poorly" as you feel it does. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6T5sK/1/